# How to get href link in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am new in Selenium and I am doing web scraping of a site, in that I want to get all href links of a tag.

I used the below code but unable to get the href link. It displays `javascript:` as output.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.clFx>a').get_attribute('href')
```

In other code, this works fine but here it shows nothing, I am also attaching the image of the inspect element area where I want to fetch the href link.

I have also checked some of the answers in Stack Overflow and used the same code still I am unable to get it.

```
<div class="clFx">
::before
<a class="userName name" href="https://resdex.naukri.com/v2/preview/preview?uniqId=6f44e0e0b95503a44378054b64bdb1cc580e0f001e115d110418475f5808004f130d020214495f5e0b544e170d6&amp;sid=3922138883&amp;paramString=2faf4d57a73f0d419d15309cbc9f5f67134f5108084a5746754e034a571b2513445055524d51250c4b0a1f57504f54030c6&amp;hfFlowName=search&amp;commentSearchType=comment-my,comment-others" target="_blank">Bhimanagoud Patil</a>
::after
</div>
```

The above href link I want to get it.

I have included below the image of the inspect element:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use anchor tag to retrieve href attribute as its associated with it. Its declare inside the web element interface and it returns the value of the web element attribute as a string

```
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
   element= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Bhimanagoud Patil"))).get_attribute("href")
   print element
```

or

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='userName name']"))).get_attribute("href")
print element
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I already used that code and again it shows javascript: as result output. Basically, when I click on the link it will open but when I try to get the href then it shows javascript:

Comment: can you share ur link ?

Comment: That is already shared in question - <div class="clFx">
::before
<a class="userName name" href="This is the link I want to get" target="_blank">Bhimanagoud Patil</a>
::after
</div>

Comment: Thats your DOM , i am asking for a link which you are trying while retrieving your element

Comment: <a class="userName name" href="https://resdex.naukri.com/v2/preview/preview?uniqId=6f44e0e0b95503a44378054b64bdb1cc580e0f001e115d110418475f5808004f130d020214495f5e0b544e170d6&amp;sid=3922138883&amp;paramString=2faf4d57a73f0d419d15309cbc9f5f67134f5108084a5746754e034a571b2513445055524d51250c4b0a1f57504f54030c6&amp;hfFlowName=search&amp;commentSearchType=comment-my,comment-others" target="_blank">Bhimanagoud Patil</a>                                                     The href tag

Comment: that's your anchor tag mate , You need to provide url where your  <a class="userName name" ...is present

Comment: That is naukri website inner page - https://resdex.naukri.com/v2/search/searchResults

Comment: I cant access it most probably you are logged in as a recruiter , Can you please provide error log

Comment: There is no error log using that code it shows only a text - javascript:

Comment: No, I didn't open the thread, so I can't :( @SeleniumUser

Answer (score 0):

You can also use xpath in this way:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="clFx"]/a').get_attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Python Selenium to scrape a site.
Here is solution for your problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("your/url/here")
link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.userName.name").get_attribute("href")
print(link)
driver.quit()
```

I hope this will help you.